# What kind of code format should I use for errors?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, formatting

I was scrolling through Stack Overflow questions when I saw this one: [Rscript Path Problem for exec() implementation R code in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66246340/13736952)

It's a beautifully structured question, except I find the way the errors are formatted to be slightly off-putting. E.g. (note that here I put `python`, but in Stack Overflow it is automatically formatted like this):

```python
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Personally, I think it'd be better for it to be formatted with `none`, which is what I usually do:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Do you think my opinion is valid, and if so should I suggest an edit to this question with my aforementioned changes?

Comment: Error messages are not source code. They might contain *some* source code but typically include free text. Yes, using monospaced formatting usually helps but syntax highlighting doesn't make sense.

Comment: These don't answer my question. I'm asking specifically about the code highlighting, not the format. Also whether I should suggest an edit.

Comment: I, personally, put errors in quote blocks, as it makes a clear distinction it is *not* code. Though some huge compile error blocks are better off in code fences. The above would seem fine in a quote block though.

Comment: I usually put errors in a code block with `lang-none` as they are basically text and not pure code. If that's the only edit you plan to do, I would avoid it. The readability difference is very small and I wouldn't waste reviewers time for such small difference

Comment: Yes, output should be formatted as code, but with syntax highlighting disabled. Whether it's a good idea to suggest that as an edit depends on your judgment. If that's the *only* thing you're fixing in the post, consider that such an edit may be rejected by reviewers as providing no substantive improvement to the post. My recommendation would be to find something else to fix also when submitting the edit.

Comment: See [Is a markup change enough improvement to be accepted as an edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405120/is-a-markup-change-enough-improvement-to-be-accepted-as-an-edit)